# how to read http request from a web page

Tags: angular, http, request

For a personal project, I need to be able to read some http requests that a web page has when some buttons are clicked, these requests have important information I need to store and use in my angular app.
How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **HttpClient**  to retreive that data from a request like this:

```
 RequestName(Parameters){return this.http.get(path)}
```

Dont forget to import it

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i will see if you're solution solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to capture requests for any request, you can attach an [`HttpInterceptor`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) to your module to intercept all request(s) before and after they are sent to the server (If this is what you are trying to accomplish, as your post is somewhat vague).

```js
@Injectable()
export class AppInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  public constructor(/* Add your services here */) { }

  public intercept(req: HttpRequest<string>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<string>> {

    // Do stuff here before passing the request to the next interceptor

    return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(() => {}, evt => {
      // use `req.url.includes('/some/path')` to test particular paths
      // example: `if(req.url.includes('/some/path') && evt.status === 200)
      if (evt.status === 200) {
        // Do stuff here after the request
      }
    }))

  }
}
```

Next, you need to provide the class to the module to intercept http requests.

```js
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AppInterceptor, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```